# Based on 1st dropdown the 2nd should be visible. It works in all browsers but not in IE (all versions)

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the following code not working in IE (all versions)?

I have 2 dropdowns. The 2nd dropdown should display based on the 1st. This is working in all browsers but not in any version of IE. Please help me out. What is the mistake in this code?

```
   <html>
   <style type="text/css">
    #navMenu {
    margin: 70px;
    padding: 40px;
         }
     #navMenu select {
    color: #000;
    background: #CD5C5C;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    width: 200px;
    font-family:"Calibri",cursive;
    text-align:center;
         }
   p.hiddenMenu {
    display: none;
            }
   p.visibleMenu {
    display: inline;
            }
  </style>

       <script type="text/javascript">
          var lastDiv = "";
          function showDiv(divName) 
          {
             if (lastDiv)
             {
               document.getElementById(lastDiv).className = "hiddenMenu";
             }   
          if (divName && document.getElementById(divName)) 
             {
               document.getElementById(divName).className = "visibleMenu";
               lastDiv = divName;
             }
           }
        </script>


  <body bgcolor="#87CEFA">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navMenu">
        <select name="category" id="statename" onchange="showDiv(this.value);">
            <option value="-1"><b>--Select State--</b></option>
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>three</option>
            <option>four</option>
            <option>five</option>
            <option>six</option>
            <option>seven</option>
        </select>
        <br class="clearFloat" /></br>

        <form id="aform">
            <p id="one" class="hiddenMenu">
                <select id="mymenu" size="1">
                    <option value="">--select--</option>
                    <option value="http://google.com">one selected</option>
                    <option value="http://google.com">two selected</option>
                </select>
        </form>
        </p>
        <script language="javascript">
            var selectmenu=document.getElementById("mymenu")
            selectmenu.onchange=function()
            {
               var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex]
               if (chosenoption.value!="nothing")
               {
                  window.open(chosenoption.value,"_parent")
               }
            }
        </script>

 </div></div>
 </body>
 </html
```

Answer (score 1):

In non IE browsers `this.value` gets label value if there is no value attr associated with options tag. But in IE it will be a empty string.

you may use like this:

```
<option value="one">one</option>
```

Comment: Thank you Rajkamal it is working fine........When we select the 2nd dropdown it moves to another page. If we come back using back button, it is showing only one dropdown...Can you help me?

Comment: please change the location.hash property,at onchange of dropdown. And during the page load we have to check the hash property and make changes accordingly.

Comment: I tried with location.hash property but i am not able to resolve it...Please kindly help me